# Error thrown for reading disposable email - Javascript

Tags: javascript, mailinator

As on date, I am reading emails from Gmail using https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap. I am fairly successful in reading and then performing the required set of operations.

However, I am in a fix now, when I am trying to do the same with a disposable email. I am particularly using https://maildrop.cc/ to send the emails from external source and reading it.

I have tried to use code mentioned here: https://github.com/daemonraco/disposable-email-reader. Every-time I perform, it throws me an error as:

> ../node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:211
>
> ^throw err;
>
> [object Object]

Code - ( I have just taken the entire code and tried to check if working fine and wasn't successful )

```
var reader = require('disposable-email-reader');

function read(){

var myInbox = new reader.MailDrop('D-16f981782oo7tsabhvg')

myInbox.list().subscribe(listResponse => {

  let list = listResponse.list();
  for (let entryKey in list) {
    let entry = list[entryKey];
    myInbox.email(entry.id).subscribe(emailResponse => {
      console.log("\nFrom: %s\nSubject: %s\n", emailResponse.from(), emailResponse.subject());
      console.log("%s\n", emailResponse.body());
    });
  }
});
}
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong and also this is very new to me through javascript. Can anyone please help.